# Karate Multiple Tags execution with AND/ OR case

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, karate, feature-file

I have following karate feature file with distinct tags for all scenarios and I want to execute scenarios with following conditions via maven command with details as,

```
Feature: Multiple Tags Execution

  @qq1
  Scenario: Test 01
    * print 'Test 0'

  @qq2
  Scenario: Test 02
    * print 'Test 02'

  @qq1 @qq2 @qq3
  Scenario: Test 03
    * print 'Test 03'

  @qq1 @qq2 @qq4
  Scenario: Test 04
    * print 'Test 04'

  @qq5
  Scenario: Test 05
    * print 'Test 05'
```

I am able to run with below mvn args for scenarios which has either of tags as `@qq1` or `@qq2` with below command as,

`mvn test "-Dkarate.options=--tags @qq1,@qq2"`

I need help for following tags conditional executions with cases below as,

1. Execute scenarios for which it has tags as both, `@qq1` AND `@qq2`,
2. Execute scenarios for which it has tags as both, `@qq1` AND `@qq2` but not `@qq3`.